# Compare two character vectors matching names

Tags: r

I have two character vectors with the different set of names and values:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
names(x) <- c("foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "grault")

y <- c("c", "a", "d", "b")
names(y) <- c("bar", "foo", "qux", "corge")
```

Is there a way to compare `x` and `y` so that we know their values corresponding to the name `bar` are different because here `x.bar = "b"` and `y.bar = "c"`? Please note the names are not ordered. I tried `setdiff` and `which(x != y)` but neither one gives me the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this:

```
x[intersect(names(x), names(y))] == y[intersect(names(x), names(y))]
```

Comment: Also, though it may look odd, `x[nms <- intersect(names(x), names(y))] == y[nms]` works as well.

Comment: do you know whether it is any different from x %in% y performance wise?

Comment: @MattBannert `x %in% y` isn't equivalent to this answer. `x %in% y` returns a logical, vector the same length as x, where for index i, this return value is FALSE if x[i] isn't in y and TRUE, otherwise.

Comment: Shame on me... Thx though.